# Selecting fieldnames dynamically based on date in Query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table with multiple fields in MS access. These fields have field names representing periods of time, such as 2011_2, 2011_3,..., 2013_9, 2013_10, ... , 2015_1, 2015_2...

How do I run a query that selects the next 12 months as the needed fields based on today's date? i.e, if today is 22 Dec 2013, it selects the fields : 2013_12, 2014_1, 2014_2, ..., 2014_12?

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Perhaps you could make an attempt?

Comment: I have tried to use SELECT (Year(Now())&"_9")  to try to simulate 2013_9 but the result returned is as follows: the field name is expr1000, and the values in that field are a column of 2013_9 in every cell of that column

Comment: Your data is in the wrong structure for handling with SQL queries. You need to normalise it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer to your question is that you can't have dynamic field names in the Access query builder. Ideally, you should modify your data so that you have one date field. That way you can specify a date range for that field in the query criteria that doesn't require the gymnastics below.

If that's not possible, though, the long answer is that you'll need to use VBA code to construct your query. The code below should create a new query in your database (cleverly called "YourQuery") that will contain the fields you need.

Since I don't know what your table is called, it'll be "table" in this example. You should change it to whatever your table is if you use this code.

You'll need to install this code in a VBA module in your database, and then devise some means of calling the function to produce the new query. For example, you could create a macro using the "RunCode" action that uses "DynamicQuery()" as the procedure to run. Note that the function call will fail if the query for this month already exists so delete that manually if you need to run it again for some reason (you could also add additional code to function to accomplish this).

Again, just because you can do something doesn't mean you should. You really should redesign your table so you don't have to resort to workarounds like this.

```
Public Function DynamicQuery()

Dim strSQL As String
dim datFieldDate As Date
Dim strYearMonth As String
Dim strThisMonth As String
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim i As Integer

Set dbs = CurrentDb

strThisMonth = Year(Date) & "_" & Month(Date)

strSQL = "SELECT table." & strThisMonth

For i = 1 to 12

datFieldDate = DateAdd("m",i,Date)
strYearMonth = Year(datFieldDate) & "_" & Month(DatFieldDate)

strSQL = strSQL & ", table." & strYearMonth

Next i

strSQL = strSQL & " FROM table;"

Set qdf = dbs.CreateQueryDef("YourQuery_" & strThisMonth, strSQL)

Set qdf = Nothing
Set dbs = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you! It managed to work with minor modifications, turns out that i need to [] all the 2013_9 because of the underscore. But great help! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a form in Access with a button on it you could create the SQL statement in code as a string, eg:

```
MyString = "SELECT " & Year(Now) & "_9" & " FROM myTable....."
```

You can then execute it via code.

You won't be able to create a "standard" query that dynamically builds a list of fields to select.